# How to wait on getter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

Below is the code of a provider class. Whenever the app starts i want to get the forms which were saved in the shared preferences. However it is taking sometime to load the from sharedpreferences. So When i access the forms for the first time it is initially empty, im getting an empty list. Is there anyway to delay the getter until it has the objects of form model.

```
class FormProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  FormProvider() {
    loadformPreferences();
  }
  List<FormModel> _forms = [];
  List<FormModel> get forms => _forms;

  Future<void> saveForm(FormModel form) async {
    _forms.add(form);
    await saveformPreferences();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> saveformPreferences() async {
    List<String> myforms = _forms.map((f) => json.encode(f.toJson())).toList();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setStringList('forms', myforms);
    
  }
  

  Future<void> loadformPreferences() async {
    // WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var result = prefs.getStringList('forms');
    if (result != null) {
      _forms = result.map((f) => FormModel.fromJson(json.decode(f))).toList();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot delay the getter. When you can get notified with notifyListeners() when the data is fetched, why do you want to delay the getter? You can just handle the UI accordingly when it is empty, and update with data when you get notified.

Comment: i checking the forms by using `Provider<of>Provider.of<FormProvider>(context, listen: false).forms`, if it is [ ], making an API call to get the forms else, im using the one from shared preferences. When i call the  `Provider<of>Provider.of<FormProvider>(context, listen: false).forms` after i kill the app, initally its returning [ ], therefore its making the api call although it has the form in shared preferences. @JigarPatel

Comment: Haven't implemented [FutureProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56989807/how-to-get-data-from-the-futureprovider-in-flutter) but might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Flutter, all actions related to building the UI must not be asynchronous (or expensive) in order to main a high frame-rate.

Thus, even if you could hypothetically find a way to "wait" for the results from SharedPreferences, this would not be desirable, since whatever waiting was done would block the UI from making progress.

Thus, there are a couple approaches to this common problem:

## Handle initial state explicitly in the UI

The simplest solution is to explicitly handle the case where the `Provider` has not yet fetched its data, by representing some sort of initial state in your `Provider`. One easy way to do this is to initialize  `_forms` to `null` instead of `[]`. Then in your `Widget.build` method, you could do something specific (like show a loading spinner) when the result is `null`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final provider = Provider.of<FormProvider>(context);
  if (provider.forms == null) {
     return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
  // Otherwise, Do something useful with provider.forms
}
```

## Construct your provider with the resolved data

Let's say that you don't use the `FormProvider` until the user performs an action, like click a button, at which point you push a new view onto the navigator with the `FormProvider`.

If you wish to guarantee that the `FormProvider` will always be initialized with the `SharedPreferences` values, then you can delay the construction of the new view until `SharedPreferences` has finished:

```dart
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Button(onClick: () async {
      final forms = await _fetchFormsFromSharedPrefs();
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageView(builder: (context) => 
        Provider(create: (_) => FormProvider(forms))));
    });
  }
}
```